# NSString cString is Deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated, c-strings

I've got another newbie question.

I've written a piece of code that converts a NSString to NSMutableData in order to simulate a webService result.

It turns out however that cString is deprecated. Can you help me replace it?
Here's my code.

```
NSString *testXMLDataString = 
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    etc....
"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

//Replace webData Received from the web service with the test Data
NSMutableData *testXMLData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[testXMLDataString cString] length:[testXMLDataString length]];
[webData setData:testXMLData];
```

Comment: It should be noted as well that when you see deprecation warnings, often going to the documents for the deprecated method will tell you what alternatives there are. For example, the docs for cString recommend using cStringUsingEncoding: or UTF8String. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-cString

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Get the raw bytes from the string.
2. Get the length of those bytes in the UTF8 encoding.
3. Create the `NSData` object using the `+dataWithBytes:length:` method.

---

```
const char *rawBytes = [testXMLDataString UTF8String];
const NSUInteger length = [testXMLDataString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSAssert(length > 0, @"Couldn't convert to UTF-8");

NSMutableData *testXMLData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:rawBytes length:length];
[webData setData:testXMLData];
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. All I did was to replace cString with UTF8String.
Thanks!

Comment: @manospro Please note that `[string length]` is not UTF-8 representation's length. It works perfectly only while `string` is actually ASCII. Use `[string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` or `[[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy]` instead.